# how to get list of objects with public shared access in google cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am trying to audit the files in the google cloud storage whether they allow all users access(publicly shared files).
I wonder whether there is a batch/API way to do that instead of using eye ball?

I searched, maybe I can use storage.objects.getIamPolicy to get the data and decide whether it's publicy shared files. I guess I also need to find out a way to list all files/objects.

If anyone has done this, please shed some lights, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) you can do a lot of Cloud Storage tasks:

- To list all objects in a bucket, you can use `$ gsutil ls
  gs://<BUCKET_NAME>`
- To list all objects in a bucket with details use `$ gsutil ls -l
  gs://<BUCKET_NAME>`
- To list all objects in a bucket with even more details use `$ gsutil
  ls -L gs://<BUCKET_NAME>`

The last one is specially useful because you can see the object permissions. The problem comes if you have a lot of objects. In this case you could write the output into a file by running `$ gsutil ls -L gs://<BUCKET_NAME> > result.txt`

In the results, the public objects show:

```
{
    "entity": "allUsers",
    "role": "READER"
}
```